# How to obtain which lines changed for each commited file with git

Tags: git, github, git-diff

I know git diff can show the differences between two commits. However, I don't know how to obtain which lines changed (example @@ -12,6 +12,11 @@) for each commited file. I already use a regex to obtain the numbers, but I would like to have them separated for each file.

In other words, I would like something like this :

```
a/aten/src/ATen/cpu/vec256/vec256_int.h
@@ -12,6 +12,11 @@
@@ -95,25 +100,19 @@
@@ -190,25 +189,19 @@
@@ -380,25 +373,19 @@

diff --git a/test/test_torch.py b/test/test_torch.py
@@ -1388,6 +1388,14 @@
```

from this output below :

```
diff --git a/aten/src/ATen/cpu/vec256/vec256_int.h b/aten/src/ATen/cpu/vec256/vec256_int.h
index 9d2581e18..5c1cf80d5 100644
--- a/aten/src/ATen/cpu/vec256/vec256_int.h
+++ b/aten/src/ATen/cpu/vec256/vec256_int.h
@@ -12,6 +12,11 @@ namespace {
 struct Vec256i {
 protected:
   __m256i values;
+
+  static inline __m256i invert(const __m256i& v) {
+    const auto ones = _mm256_set1_epi64x(-1);
+    return _mm256_xor_si256(ones, v);
+  }
 public:
   Vec256i() {}
   Vec256i(__m256i v) : values(v) {}
@@ -95,25 +100,19 @@ struct Vec256<int64_t> : public Vec256i {
     return _mm256_cmpeq_epi64(values, other.values);
   }

@@ -190,25 +189,19 @@ struct Vec256<int32_t> : public Vec256i {
     return _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(values, other.values);
   }

@@ -380,25 +373,19 @@ struct Vec256<int16_t> : public Vec256i {
     return _mm256_cmpeq_epi16(values, other.values);
   }


diff --git a/test/test_torch.py b/test/test_torch.py
index 0c30c1f1a..10f6085cf 100644
--- a/test/test_torch.py
+++ b/test/test_torch.py
@@ -1388,6 +1388,14 @@ class _TestTorchMixin(object):
     def test_neg(self):
         self._test_neg(self, lambda t: t)

+    def test_threshold(self):
+        for dtype in torch.testing.get_all_dtypes():
+            if dtype != torch.uint8 and dtype != torch.float16:
+                # 100 is wide enough to use AVX2 instructions for all types
+                x = torch.randn(100).sign().to(dtype=dtype)
+                y = torch.threshold(x, 0, 0)
+                self.assertTrue(y.le(0).any())
+
     def test_reciprocal(self):
         a = torch.randn(100, 89)
         res_div = 1 / a
```

Note : I am using Python language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing if something already exists, I developped something to achieve this.

First, I split the `patchfile` string using `'diff --git'` as separators. This will return a separate `patchfile` for each file changed (all stored in `split_patchfile`) :

```py
    def splitPatchfile(patchfile):
        split_patchfile = patchfile.split('diff --git')
        return split_patchfile
```

Second, I parse every `patchfile` to find the changed lines. This will create the 2Dimensional-ish `list` that are saved in `lines_numbers`. Each `line_number` will contain the changed lines of each patchfile.

```py
    def findChangedLinesPerFile(split_patchfile):
        lines_numbers = []
        for split_patch in split_patchfile:
            lines_numbers.append(findChangedLines(split_patch))
        return lines_numbers

    def findChangedLines(split_patch):
        regex = r"^@@ [-+](\d+)"
        matches = re.finditer(regex, split_patch, re.MULTILINE)
        line_numbers = []

        for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
            # print(int(match.group(1))) # debug which lines are modified
            line_numbers.append(int(match.group(1)))
        return line_numbers
```

Third, since the order of elements is important for further work, I clear empty elements to make correspond each `patchfile` to its `line_numbers`.
Empty elements appear because of `patchfile.split('diff --git')`. It created 3 `patchfile` because I had 2 `'diff --git'` (the first `patchfile` was empty).

```py
    def removeEmptyElements(split_patchfile, lines_numbers):
        split_patchfile = list(filter(None, split_patchfile))
        lines_numbers = list(filter(None, lines_numbers))
        return split_patchfile, lines_numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but **git log -p** will show the patch from each commit.
From that it would be possible to make a script just showing the part you want, if git does not have a feature which does it for you.